# Typescript forwardRef error in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-forwardref

I have onboarding and slide components . I am passing ref as a prop to slide component from onboarding component with forwardRef . It works fine but typescript gives me an error

My components are like below

```
const Onboarding = () => {
  const { width } = useOrientation();
  const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0);
  const scroll = useRef<Animated.ScrollView>(null);
  const onScroll = (event: any) => {
    Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }]);
  };

  return (
    <Box flex={1}>
      <Animated.ScrollView
        ref={scroll}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        horizontal
      >
        {slides.map((data, index) => (
          <Slide key={index} data={data} ref={scroll} {...{ index, scrollX }} />
        ))}
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    </Box>
  );
};

interface SlideProps {
  data: {
    label: string;
    description: string;
    src: string;
  };
  scrollX: Animated.Value<0>;
  index: number;
}

export const Slide = forwardRef<Animated.ScrollView, SlideProps>(
  ({ data, scrollX, index }: SlideProps, ref) => {
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

    const aspect = height / width;

    return (
      <Box flex={1} width={width} backgroundColor="mainBackground">
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() =>
              //error here
            ref?.current?.getNode().scrollTo({ x: width * (index + 1), y: 0 })
          }
        >
          <Text>heyy</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Box>
    );
  }
);
```

Error is like this;
Property 'current' does not exist on type '((instance: ScrollView | null) => void) | MutableRefObject<ScrollView | null>'.
How can I fix this issue ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest, it feels weird to see the `forwardRef` in this context. I mean, what you really want is to have the ref referencing the `Animated.ScrollView`, not the Slide object.

Option 1 (ugly in my opinion): pass the `ref` as a property of `Slide` (not as the ref itself).

Option 2 (which I prefer): make `Slide` tell `Onboarding` that the press event happened and make Onboarding do the `scrollTo`

```js
const Onboarding = () => {
  const { width } = useOrientation();
  const scrollX = new Animated.Value(0);
  const scroll = useRef<Animated.ScrollView>(null);
  const onScroll = (event: any) => {
    Animated.event([{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { x: scrollX } } }]);
  };
  const onPress = (width: number, index: number) => {
    scroll.current?.getNode().scrollTo({ x: width * (index + 1), y: 0 })
  }

  return (
    <Box flex={1}>
      <Animated.ScrollView
        ref={scroll}
        scrollEventThrottle={16}
        onScroll={onScroll}
        horizontal
      >
        {slides.map((data, index) => (
          <Slide key={index} onPress={onPress} data={data} {...{ index, scrollX }} />
        ))}
      </Animated.ScrollView>
    </Box>
  );
};

interface SlideProps {
  // same as before
  onPress: (width:number, index:number) => void
}

export const Slide = ({ data, scrollX, index, onPress }: SlideProps) => {
    const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");

    const aspect = height / width;

    return (
      <Box flex={1} width={width} backgroundColor="mainBackground">
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => onPress(width, index)}
        >
          <Text>heyy</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </Box>
    );
  }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Why is forwardRef weird? Can you explain ? I want to comprehend it

Comment: Yes, sure!
ForwardRef, as shown here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html, is when you want to forward a ref, created by the parent, to a single child.
What you are trying to do is to share the ref between two children.

If you see in your example, you create the scroll ref in Onboard component and forward that to Animated.ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks for your help it helped me a lot to understand